# Blobstore createUploadUrl() returning a non-verifiable URL to Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-endpoints

My App Engine instance suddenly started playing funny once I upgraded the SDK and re-ran generation of the endpoints. createUploadUrl() is returning a URL in the format

**https://[version].my-app.appspot.com**

It mentions this in the documentation

> Please note that in April of 2013, Google will stop issuing SSL certificates for double-wildcard domains hosted at appspot.com (i.e. *.*.appspot.com). If you rely on such URLs for HTTPS access to your application, please change any application logic to use "-dot-" instead of ".". For example, to access version "1" of application "myapp" use "`https://1-dot-myapp.appspot.com`" instead of "`https://1.myapp.appspot.com`." If you continue to use "`https://1.myapp.appspot.com`" the certificate will not match, which will result in an error for any User-Agent that expects the URL and certificate to match exactly.

Do I need to change anything on my side? I thought this change would happen automatically.

I've tried changing the URL in code, which causes it to POST but then the upload-handler Servlet is never called. If I attempt to POST to it without a change then Android throws a Hostname was not verified error.